# PHP PDO MYSQL Compound Select Statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
Table1
    id   |   username   | request
 --------|--------------|----------
     1   |    user 1    | blah blah  
     2   |    user 1    | blah2
     3   |    user 1    | blah3
     4   |    user 1    | blah4
     5   |    user 2    | blah1

Table2
    id   |   username   |  requestID
 --------|--------------|------------
     1   |    user 2    |      1
```

The returned results for 'user 2' should be:

```
table1.id = 2
table1.id = 3
table1.id = 4
```

I need to create a select that will select all id's from the first table where the username <> $username (thats easy enough).

I also need this matched against table 2 to ensure the $username does not already have said id from table 1 matching RequestID from table 2 (this is where I have no idea what to do).

I know how to do an inner join, but this seems a little more complex than that. Do I join two different selects together? How do I do this?

Existing code:

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE username <> :user");
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

**Adding to question**

I have tried a inner join and it just returns an error on the second WHERE clause: Unknown column 'table2.username' in 'where clause'.. yet looking the table clearly has a username column.

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT table1.id 
    FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.requestID 
    WHERE table1.username <> 'user 1' 
    AND table2.username = 'user 1'");
```

**ADDING MORE TO TRY TO MAKE IT MORE CLEAR**

I do not believe a simple INNER JOIN will solve my problem as I originally stated. I need to first get the results from table1. Then I need those results tested against table2 so that ONLY results from table1 NOT MADE by the current user are returned, and of those returned results only the ones the user does not have listed in table2 should be returned.

So I am guessing I am just going to have to do two completely separate database functions.

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE username <> :user");
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$id = $row['id'];

$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT requestID FROM table1 WHERE username = :user");
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$rid = $stmt->fetch();

if $rid !== $id { //perform function } else {}
```

I thought there was a way to compound select statements so I didn't have to do 2 different calls, but perhaps I am wrong. Either way I don't see how inner join is going to accomplish this... but I am open to learning.

**STILL MORE UPDATES TRYING TO MAKE THIS EVEN MORE CLEAR**

table1.id = 1 should not match because user 2 has a table2.requestID that matches table1.id; table1.id = 5 should not match because user 2 is the listed username for table1.id = 5

However the other 3 columns should return.

Comment: use simple  inner join i think it will work

Comment: How should your output with table1 and table2?show sample output to we

Comment: I updated the status of the question to try to show I have tried inner join and its not working.

Comment: @ashkufaraz trying this question update one final time. I really don't see how this can be done with INNER JOIN....

Comment: can you please explain more what do you mean of `ensure the $username does not already have said id from table 1 matching RequestID from table 2`

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is the exact same outcome of the final bit of code I posted in my question, only without doing two separate select statements, 2 separate database connections, 2 separate variables, then testing between them. I want to compound the 2 selects into one, and get the results returned in one single database call.

Comment: i made db like the one you described and tried the query `SELECT table1.id 
    FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.requestID 
    WHERE table1.username <> 'user 1' 
    AND table2.username = 'user 1'` it does work no error but no result as well

Comment: changing `user 1` to `user 2` give `id 1`

Comment: People are very confused by this question. The only reason I edited the post and added the bit about the inner join is because the comments suggested inner join should work, but my understanding of inner join which I have used countless times, is that it will never return my end result I need compound select statements, as I asked about in my question. Seriously ignore everything except that last piece of code.... I want to know how to achieve that in one single select statement instead of 2 separate ones.

Comment: can you please see my answer and tell me why it's wrong ?

Comment: `ADDING MORE TO TRY TO MAKE IT MORE CLEAR` Sometimes less is more. Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements AND a desired result. You might also consider the benefits that an OUTER JOIN can confer.

Comment: @robert check my latest updates to the question, I cannot make it more clear than that :)

Comment: @Strawberry if you notice each bold statement, was me trying to bring clarity. The original question, was a LOT LESS. the immediate reply was "inner join" despite have suggested an inner join won't work for this. I did in my latest update add the end result i am searching for. I'd consider anything that would solve my issue, but what little i have ever researched on JOIN vs INNER JOIN vs OUTER JOIN is they are interchangeable, so I don't know when to use which or how... I just know inner join which I can take or leave the word INNER from.

Comment: I am honestly not sure what you are getting at in your comment. That I should not add more to make it more clear because less is sometimes more? But SO specifically states you should keep adding updates to your questions to show progress and clarity. I was doing exactly that. Or perhaps you were suggesting my answer is outter join? Or that you recommended outer join cause my limited research is correct and they are interchangeable? Can we tell I am confused? In any event I am still trying to figure out how to join these 2 select statements. Based on the replies, I am guessing it cant be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using [IN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

```
SELECT table1.id
FROM table1
WHERE table1.username <> 'user 2'
and NOT table1.id IN (SELECT requestid FROM table2 WHERE username = 'user 2')
```

or using left join

```
SELECT table1.id
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.requestID
WHERE table1.username <> 'user 2'
and ( table2.username <> 'user 2' OR table2.username IS NULL )
```

i don't know which one is better but they have the same results

Comment: Add this to table1: id => 2; id => 3; id =>4; username => user1; username => user1; username => user1; request => blah2; request => blah3;  request => blah4; Your end result should only return table1.id=2, table1.id=3, and table1.id=4. Because those would be the only results not made by user2 in table1  and in which user2 also doesn't have a listed table2.requestID that matches table1.id

Comment: Neither is better as neither solves the question asked which is why there are no answers marketed correct. As I have said since I first posted this question, I don't believe join will work. Join requires matching data, and there is no matching data. I am trying to match on the absence of matching data, which is why the question title states COMPOUND SELECT STATEMENT - ie the practice of adding two very separate select statements with very separate where clauses and no matching info into 1 single statement.

Comment: have you checked the result ? both give you only 2 3 4 and not 1 or 5

Comment: TY TY TY TY TY IF I could like and up this more I would :)

Comment: you are welcome, can you please edit the question and make it more clear without the add more to make it clear so if some other users come can understand the problem without having headache

Comment: if you don't understand the query you should ask in a comment about it

Comment: I actually get it perfectly, and have made your recommended edits. TY again!.

Answer (score 0):

Use condition in section `on`

Try this

```
SELECT table1.id 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.requestID  and table2.username = 'user 1'
WHERE table1.username <> 'user 1'
```

Comment: The problem  at this point is I don't know how to ask the question. I actually don't believe an inner join is the answer as originally stated in the question - as an inner join can't match the data against the return of the data. I need all results returned from table1 where the username is not the current user AND I need those returns matched against table2 to ensure the user has not already completed them.

Comment: the one he did is the correct way and it doesn't have an error